# How are consistency violations handled in event sourcing?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, referential-integrity, aggregateroot

First of all, let me state that I am new to Command Query Responsibility Segregation and Event Sourcing (Message-Drive Architecture), but I'm already seeing some significant design benefits. However, there are still a few issues on which I'm unclear.

Say I have a `Customer` class (an aggregate root) that contains a property called `postalAddress` (an instance of the `Address` class, which is a value object). I also have an `Order` class (another aggregate root) that contains (among `OrderItem` objects and other things) a property called `deliveryAddress` (also an instance of the `Address` class) and a string property called `status`.

The customer places an order by issueing a `PlaceOrder` command, which triggers the `OrderReceived` event. At this point in time, the status of the order is `"RECEIVED"`. When the order is shipped, someone in the warehouse issues an `ShipOrder` command, which triggers the `OrderShipped` event. At this point in time, the status of the order is `"SHIPPED"`.

One of the business rules is that if a `Customer` updates their `postalAddress` before an order is shipped (i.e., while the status is still `"RECEIVED"`), the `deliveryAddress` of the `Order` object should also be updated. If the status of the `Order` were already `"SHIPPED"`, the `deliveryAddress` would not be updated.

**Question 1. Is the best place to put this "conditionally cascading address update" in a Saga (a.k.a., Process Manager)?** I assume so, given that it is translating an event ("The customer just updated their postal address...") to a command ("... so update the delivery address of order 123").

**Question 2. If a Saga is the right tool for the job, how does it identify the orders that belong to the user, given that an aggregate can only be retrieved by it's unique ID (in my case a UUID)?**

Continuing on, given that each aggregate represents a transactional boundary, if the system were to crash **after** the `Customer`'s `postalAddress` was updated (the `CustomerAddressUpdated` event being persisted to the event store) but **before** the `OrderDeliveryAddressUpdated` could be updated (i.e., between the two transactions), then the system is left in an inconsistent state.

**Question 3. How are such "violations" of consistency rules detected and rectified?**

Answer (score 3):

In most instances the delivery address of an order should be independent of any other data change as a customer may want he order sent to an arbitrary address.  That being said, I'll give my 2c on how you could approach this:

> Is the best place to handle this in a process manager?

Yes.  You should have an `OrderProcess`.

> How would one get hold of the correct `OrderProcess` instance given that it can only be retrieve by aggregate id?

There is nothing preventing one from adding any additional lookup mechanism that associates data to an aggregate id.  In my experimental, going-live-soon, mechanism called [shuttle-recall](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-recall/) I have a `IKeyStore` mechanism that associates any arbitrary key to an AR Id.  So you would be able to associate something like `[order-process]:customerId=CID-123;` as a key to some aggregate.

> How are such "violations" of consistency rules detected and rectified?

In most cases they could be handled out-of-band, if possible.  Should I order something from Amazon and I attempt to change my address after the order has shipped the order is still going to the original address.  If your case of linking the customer postal address to the active order address you could notify the customer that *n* number of orders have had their addresses updated but that a recent order (within some tolerance) has not.

As for the system going down before processing you should have some guaranteed delivery mechanism to handle this.  I do not regard these domain event in the same way I regard system events in a messaging infrastructure such as a service bus.

Just some thoughts :)

Comment: Appreciate the insights. I was thinking that the `OrderProcessManager` object could provide a cache/index (a map of customer UUIDs to a vector of order UUIDs for those orders that have not been shipped, in this way being "stateful"), and when the `OrderProcessManager` sees the `OrderShipped` event, it simply removes the order UUID from it's internal cache, but your idea of arbitrary key/value pairs stored in the event store against an aggregate is insightful.

Comment: `How would one get hold of the correct OrderProcess instance given that it can only be retrieve by aggregate id?` Wait... are you saying that Process Manager objects are also stored in a repository (e.g., an `OrderProcess` is stored in an `OrderProcessRepository` - with the use of ES of course)???

Comment: Having an `OrderProcessRepository` *is* an option in a custom implementation world.  if you use C# I have 3 implementations of a process manager in the [samples for my service bus](https://github.com/Shuttle/shuttle-esb-samples) under the `Shuttle.ProcessManagement` folder.  The main point is that there is a bit of data that you are going to **know**, such as the customer number.  In the code handling the creation of the initial stream you should have access to that data and at *that* point you would create the association between the AR Id and the arbitrary key.

Comment: The query side of your implementation could also contain that association so you may not need something like the `IKeyStore`.  However, if you can, say, have only one active order per customer (silly, but just as an example) you could use the key store to determine whether there is an active key/id association to prevent a duplicate.

Comment: Appreciate your input. Still ruminating on ideas. Would you mind sharing your thoughts on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250464/when-using-mda-should-you-differentiate-between-idempotent-and-non-idempotent-e